# laravel 5.2 - How to setup amazon s3 file storage

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-5

I am trying to setup Amazon s3 on my project.

In composer.json  I placed this:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0"
    },
```

Then run this command in cmd:

```
Composer update
```

In filesystems.php I set following:

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => 'key',
            'secret' => 'secret',
            'region' => 'region',
            'bucket' => 'buket',
        ],
```

Now in controller I added this:

```
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
```

and trying to create directory on s3:

```
\Storage::disk('s3')->makeDirectory('1');
```

And getting this error:

```
'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!' in E:\wamp\www\phocus\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:314
```

Please guide me.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

I restored my project and run this command from my project's directory:

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3
```

and It worked.

Thanx